# What's wrong with this ninepatch image?

Tags: android, nine-patch

I cannot understand, why this 9patch image is not being set as ninepatch in my android app.
For some reason, it's showing it as a regular png file.

Weird thing is, both the draw9patch tool and the Eclipse build in UI designer, show the image correctly (it's being expanded correctly), but not on the nexus 7.

I'm attaching the image.

[image: Google+ button 9patch]

It's not the filename, as the 9patch was created with the draw9patch tool and the filename is "**google_button.9.png**"

**This is the XML code**

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_googleplus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/google_button"
            android:minWidth="300dp"
            android:text="@string/login_login_with_google"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
```

Comment: What's its file name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the 9-patch wasn't ok, I simplified to this one. Please, give it a try. When I use 9-patches, I only put top and left edges marks; I guess putting marks all around the png was causing the mess at some point.

[image: 9-patch image updated]

Comment: Mmh the same issue here, let me do some tests.

Comment: I attached a new png to my answer.

Comment: Yes, this works, but can you tell me what was wrong with my 9patch image?

Comment: Not sure why, but I had problems before when putting mark pixels on both sides of the 9-patch (left & right, top & bottom).

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to learn by the mistake so I don't make it again... My understanding is that left and top markers mark the repeatable parts and the space between them is left as it is.

Comment: Yes, that's right. And right-bottom markers have no effect apparently, so there's no reason to put them. I suppose when the device finds the drawable has black pixels on all the edges, somehow it thinks that is a normal resource instead of a 9-patch.

Comment: Right and bottom edges set the content of the button. So they have a reason to be there. But it makes no sense why putting a second marker on top kills the 9patch. I'm doing tests and it seems that setting the right and bottom (content) markers creates the issue

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it is in drawable-hdpi, otherwise it gets rescaled, and one pixel black do not scale well sometimes. For such images it is best to have them for all dpis

Comment: it's in the drawable-xhdpi folder

Answer (score 0):

Is the background of the 9patch image fully transparent or white?

API Guides says,

> The border is used to define the stretchable and static areas of the image. You indicate a stretchable section by drawing one (or more) 1-pixel-wide black line(s) in the left and top part of the border (the other border pixels should be fully transparent or white).

Comment: Yes, the image was saved as 24bit png image from photoshop (transparent) then saved as 9patch by the draw9patch tool

Answer (score 0):

Lefteris, I found this tutorial helpful in understanding why I had issues with NinePatch images (images and guides) created in Photoshop:

http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/

Specifically, this paragraph:

> Also you should keep in mind that remaining area of the one-pixel
>   outline must be completely transparent. This includes the four corners
>   of the image – those should always be clear. This can be a bigger
>   problem than you realize. For example, if you scale an image in
>   Photoshop it will add anti-aliased pixels which may include
>   almost-invisible pixels which will also cause it to fail*. If you must
>   scale in Photoshop, use the Nearest Neighbor setting in the Resample
>   Image pulldown menu (at the bottom of the Image Size pop-up menu) to
>   keep sharp edges on your guides.

I found that preparing the images first in Photoshop, then using the draw9patch tool to draw the guides was the best way to create *working* NinePatch images. The nice thing about the tool is that it will point out problematic areas. And as mentioned, the right and bottom guides are not necessary since you can specify content areas easily by leaving the 1px border off of the top and left areas you don't want to stretch - The following is an example banner I needed to place at the bottom of a screen. I needed to ensure both content areas did not stretch. Additionally, I also wanted to ensure stretching didn't occur to the left side of the left content area and the right side of the right content area:

[image]

Hope this helps.